# Remove part of string between two indexOf in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i remove from a string between two `indexOf`

i have this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/ertcp/)

here is my code :

```
 var x = "M 178.6491699876038 23.419570090792845 C 183.6491699876038 
23.419570090792845 186.47776067057902 30.902823043098138 190.3670728596699 
     41.19229585251793 L 194.25638504876076 51.48176866193772" ; 
  var c = x.indexOf('C') ; 
  var L = x.indexOf('L') ;
  var final = x.slice (c,L) ;
  console.log(final) ;
```

this code will result in returning the removed part of the string

**QUESTION** how can i return the original string after removing the part between `C` and `L`

​

Comment: whats wrong with just using X?

Comment: what do you mean by using x ??????????????????????????????

Comment: Nevermind, from your wording, I thought you just wanted your oringinal string, which would of been in X, not your orginal string minus the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace that part of the original string with nothing :

```
var x = "M 178.6491699876038 23.419570090792845 C 183.6491699876038 23.419570090792845 186.47776067057902 30.902823043098138 190.3670728596699 41.19229585251793 L 194.25638504876076 51.48176866193772" ; 
var c = x.indexOf('C') ; 
var L = x.indexOf('L') ;

var final = x.slice (c,L) ;
console.log(x.replace(final, ''));
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ertcp/1/)

Answer (score 9):

```
var c = x.indexOf('C') ; 
var L = x.indexOf('L') ;

var remaining = x.slice(0, c) + x.slice(L);
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ePbCP/

Comment: var remaining = x.slice(0, c-1) + x.slice(L-1, x.length);

result:
M 178.6491699876038 23.419570090792845 L 194.25638504876076 51.4817686619377

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky: That removes the `'L'`.  I don't think that is the desired result.

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky: Why is that better than what's posted in the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 `substring`s for this.

```
var c = x.indexOf('C') ; 
var L = x.indexOf('L') ;

var y = x.substring(0, c) + x.substring(L);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var x = "M 178.6491699876038 23.419570090792845 C 183.6491699876038 23.419570090792845 186.47776067057902 30.902823043098138 190.3670728596699 41.19229585251793 L 194.25638504876076 51.48176866193772";
var c = x.indexOf('C');
var L = x.indexOf('L');
var final = x.substring(0, c) + x.substring(L, x.length);
console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the final string with empty string to get the remaining part.

```
var remaining = x.replace(final,'');
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/ertcp/4/)