# Delete part of string between { and | in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Currently I am getting strings that look like this:

> I like {{Pizza|Pasta}} for breakfast.

I want to manipulate strings in JS so that they only contain the part after the '|' so that the sentence would be

> I like Pasta for breakfast.

So far this piece of code has brought me a fair end.

```
str.replace(/\{\{.*?\|.*?\}\}/g, "");
```

But if I have a string like:

> I eat {{bread}} and {{cereal|yoghurt}} for breakfast.

The results is:

> I eat yoghurt for breakfast.

But I want:

> I eat bread and yoghurt for breakfast.

So far I have tried this with regex. But it doesn't seem to replace anything.

```
str.replace(/\{\{.*((?!]).).*?\|(.*?)\}\}/g, "");
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I have tried splitting at the '|' the string and deleting the first part, but then I have the problem that I delete things that I don't want to delete, in the example the 'I like' part

Comment: So give a [mre] showing the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove part of string between two indexOf in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566505/remove-part-of-string-between-two-indexof-in-javascript)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Did you not understand my question?

Comment: I understand what you're trying to achieve, but it's unclear what the specific problem with your current code is. Note that SO isn't a code-writing or tutorial service (see the [tour] and [ask])

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you know a place where I can ask questions such as this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the perfect use case for a regular expression. You could use one to find all occurances of `{{...|...}}` and replace them with the part between `|` and `}}`

```js
let string = "I like {{Pizza|Pasta}} for breakfast and {{Pasta|Pizza}} for lunch."

console.log(string.replace(/\{\{.*?\|(.*?)\}\}/g, "$1"));
```

And there they are, multiple placeholders :D

> thanks for the help but I unfortunately have another problem. If I have the string "I eat {{bread}} and {{yoghurt|cereal}} for breakfast" it will results in "I eat cereal for breakfast, but I don't want the bread part to disappear.

It does that, because here you have changed the pattern for the placeholder. From exactly `{{...|...}}` *(what the regex above covers)* to a `|`-sperated list of entries inside of the `{{...}}`.

There are basically two ways to go about this.

Change the regex to reflect that that list:

```js
let string = "I eat {{bread}} and {{yoghurt|cereal}} for breakfast"

console.log(string.replace(/{{(?:.*?\|)*?([^|]*?)}}/g, "$1"));
```

Or the we go a bit simpler with the regex and let a function deal with its content:

```js
let string = "I eat {{bread}} and {{yoghurt|cereal}} for breakfast"

console.log(string.replace(
  // the placeholder is simply `{{....}}`
  /{{(.*?)}}/g, 
  // the function takes the content between `{{` and `}}` 
  // splits it by `|` and returns the last item
  (match, content) => content.split("|").pop()
));
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me! Thank you.

Comment: You dont need to escape curely braces, nether you need to add the interogation mark, it can be just `console.log(string.replace(/{{.*\|(.*)}}/g, "$1"));`

Comment: @SaymoinSam I'm surprised about the curly braces because they are used for intervals `/\d{3,5}/` and therefore a syntax element imo. But you seem to be right. *"... nether you need to add the interogation mark"* nor do you need the `g` flag. Unless you want to support multiple matches. And then you get in trouble with greedy `.*` selectors. Without the interogation marks, the regex will match everything from the first `{{` to the last `}}` as a single match.

Comment: Ah I didnt see the global modifier `g`

Comment: No problem. It wasn't a requirement by OP, but from personal experience, it won't take long untill it will become a requirement. And it was simply too simple to include.

Comment: Hello @Thomas, thanks for the help but I unfortunately have another problem. If I have the string "I eat {{bread}} and {{yoghurt|cereal}} for breakfast" it will results in "I eat cereal for breakfast, but I don't want the bread part to disappear. I have tried the following regex without any luck. \{\{.*((?!]).).*?\|(.*?)\}\}. I basically try to see if there is a '}' inbetweet the { and |, but this doesn't seem to work. Would you happen to know how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
var text = '{{Pizza|Pasta}}';
var replaced = text.replace('{{','').replace('}}','').split('|')[1];
var final = 'I like '+replaced+' for breakfast';
console.log(final);
```